# Eclipse Plugin Development: Adding items to a working set with the path of the item?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-neon, working-set

**Hello,** 
I'm an eclipse plugin development newbie looking for pointers to get me started on a particular project.

I am trying to build an eclipse plugin that will automatically construct a working set from a text file that simply consists of a list of file path names. The files/items need not share any parent directories. The rough idea is represented in the following diagram:

[image: Diagram of the plugin's goal]

I am **not** asking for the solution to this task. That's the over-arching goal. To achieve that goal, I want to conquer some smaller goals first.

**With that in mind, here's the smaller goal I'm currently trying to tackle:**

### **In Eclipse, how can I prompt the user for a single file's path, and then add that file to an existing working set?**

I'm not sure where to start. Should I work directly off of the existing org.eclipse.ui.workingSets extension point? Or should I use a collection of other extension points? How do I convert strings into something that can be added to a working set? Do I write code that directly modifies the workingsets.xml file?

Even with a much simpler goal, I still feel quite overwhelmed with the vastness of eclipse extension options. There are probably many ways to go about implementing something like this, but I just need one to get started.

**Thanks a bunch!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate working sets you use the working set manager interface `IWorkingSetManager`. Get this with:

```java
IWorkingSetManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();
```

From this you can get a particular working by name with:

```java
IWorkingSet workingSet = manager.getWorkingSet("name");
```

The contents of a working set is an array of `IAdaptable` objects:

```java
IAdaptable [] contents = workingSet.getElements();
```

You add to the contents by adding to this array and setting the contents:

```java
IAdaptable [] newContents 

.... get new array with old contents + new contents

workingSet.setElements(newContents);
```

A lot of Eclipse objects implement `IAdaptable`, for a file in the workspace you would use `IFile`. You can use dialogs such as `ResourceSelectionDialog` to select resources from the workspace.

Comment: This is a solid answer. I think it's enough to get me started, so I'm accepting it. I really appreciate it greg!